# Como calcular a distância de dispositivos pelo WI-FI usando força e frequência de sinal?

Tags: c, shell

Como posso realizar o calculo de distância de um device pelo wifi, usando a força do sinal do mesmo?

Estou utilizando o tshark (wireshark) para realizar essa sondagem do padrão 802.11, capturando apenas requisições prob (momento em que o device procura por APs). Em seguida filtro os campos que me interesam como MAC address do emissor, signal strength e dentre outros.

Comando shell (Com filtro de MAC):

```
tshark -l -i wlxe894f617588c -Y "wlan.fc.type_subtype == 4 && wlan.sa == xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" -T fields -e wlan_radio.timestamp -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e wlan_radio.signal_dbm  -e wlan_radio.frequency
```

Output

```
1614649110  xx:xx:xx:XX:XX:XX   Broadcast   -34 2412
1614751459  xx:xx:xx:XX:XX:XX   Broadcast   -40 2412
1615400027  xx:xx:xx:XX:XX:XX   Broadcast   -74 2412
1615514449  xx:xx:xx:XX:XX:XX   Broadcast   -74 2412
1615672377  xx:xx:xx:XX:XX:XX   Broadcast   -86 2412
```

Das colunas acima uso apenas as duas ultimas que são força e frequência do sinal. Para realizar o seguinte calculo:

> distance = 10 ^ ((27.55 - (20 * log10(frequency)) + signalLevel)/20)

Descrito como resposta [How to calculate distance from Wifi router using Signal Strength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength)
Ele ainda informa:

> Example: frequency = 2412MHz, signalLevel = -57dbm, result = 7.000397427391188m

Porém quando realizo o calculo com esses valores o resultado é totalmente diferente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float r = pow(10.0,((27.55 - (20 * log10(2414))+ -57)/20.0));
    printf("%d\n",r); // resultado 0.000014
    return 0;
}
```

Há outras respostas que envolvem o calculo FSPL (Free Space Path Lost), porém requer variáveis as quais não possuo, tais como sensibilidade de recepção da antena ou o seu ganho.

Obviamente não é fácil obter a distância exata do device, já que a força de sinal é sensivel a qualquer barreira física e ou interferências de mesma frequencia. 
O objetivo mesmo é saber quantos devices estão próximos a minha antena num raio de 5 metros ou mais se necessário estando conectados ou não.

Comment: Isso seria um problema de matemática, independnte de estar em um código, não? Acredito que isso não traz o problema para o [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). De qq forma, seria fechada por erro de digitação, se fosse considerar no escopo, pq se trata de erro ao copiar a fórmula esquecendo do ABS. Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help].  Lembrando ainda que seus pontos já permitem acesso ao chat da rede, mais adequado para esse tipo de coisa (em especial a sala Estouro de Pilha)

Comment: Realmente. Agora percebo que é uma questão volta mais para fisica/eletronica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testei aqui no matlab:

Frequency em `2412`

signallevel em `-57`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu código tá faltando um `abs` olha lá na fórmula da imagem:

```
abs(-57)
```

Equação correta para os dados acima:

```
10 ^ ((27.55 - (20 * log10(2412)) + abs(-57))/20)
```